# Python2.7 looping through custom sequence

Tags: loops, python-2.7, range

Rookie questions season continues :)

I've got a function that has to be fed with numerical value from certain range. This part of the code will be replicated for each datasource I'm linking in, but which changed numerical parameters.

**Example (that works):**

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 15, 31, 32]:
    RowTDE(i)
```

**Question**

I would like to avoid typing in all the necessary values, therefore I would like to use something like this:

```
for i in [:2]+[7:10]+[15:]:
    RowTDE(i)
```

I've tried it and got:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Do I need to create a list of integers first to use it? Like

```
intList = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 33].
```

Also, as mentioned previously for each data source this range will differ, but maximum numerical value will be less then 40 (each number represents a column index).

As always I would much appreciate your help with this and just let me know if you need more info.

Happy Monday morning :)

Comment: Pretty sure you want `range(33)`?

Comment: Well would range(33) bring back 0:33? I need only specific column numbers i.e. for column 0:3 and 5:7.

Comment: Slice notation is on objects that support it. It can't exist on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `range`s:

```
>>> for i in range(3) + range(7, 9) + range(15, 16) + range(31, 33):
        print i


0
1
2
7
8
15
31
32
```

or build the `range` *then* slice it:

```
>>> r = range(33)
>>> for i in r[:3] + r[7:9] + r[15:16] + r[31:]:
    print i


0
1
2
7
8
15
31
32
```

But you can't slice nothing, hence `[:2]` on its own is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe, this is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Slice notation on its own doesn't make sense. It's implemented by objects that support it using the `__getitem__` method.

You could (ab)use `__getitem__` to create an object that uses that syntax:

```
import itertools

class SliceAbuse(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        last = None

        for obj in key:
            if isinstance(obj, slice):
                for n in xrange(obj.start, obj.stop + 1, obj.step or 1):
                    last = n
                    yield n
            elif obj is Ellipsis:
                for n in itertools.count(last + 1):
                    yield n
            else:
                last = obj
                yield obj
```

For example:

```
for n in SliceAbuse()[1:5, 7:9, 11, ...]:  # To infinity and beyond
    print n

    if n == 20:
        break
```

Although since your ranges are rather small, you can use the fact that `range()` in Python 2 returns a list object, which you can concatenate with other lists:

```
range(1, 4) + range(10, 15) == [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Note that this won't work in Python 3, as `range` doesn't return a list.

Comment: Thank you Blender for the suggestion. I think I will stick to jon's answer, as a little bit more simplistic to implement :)

Comment: @dce: Yeah, I sort of missed the "under 40 elements" part.

Comment: But will keep your post as well, might need it in the future! :)